# Analyze Windows Malware on Linux

Tags: malware, windows, linux

I'm just getting started with the book 'Practical Malware Analysis', some of the exercises are using PEview and Dependency Walker however I'm slightly allergic to using Windows.

Is it possible to analyze windows malware on linux without using VM's or does this require using Windows?

Comment: It all depends on the type of analysis that you want to perform.

Comment: @schroeder I would be wanting this to be static and dynamic so i assume I may need to use windows

Comment: Sandboxes sound like the tool you are looking for

Comment: Yes but that would involve running windows in a VM right? I wanted to avoid windows at all cost

Comment: No. Please look up malware sandbox options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *is* possible to analyze windows malware on linux - but you'll be limited when it comes to analyzing runtime behaviour. `wine` is good, but to observe the behaviour of the malware, you'll need a debugging vm with windows.